# If there is no data for a specific field, no data is returned

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I'm using a left outer join query to bind the query results in a `apex:inputField` inside the `apex:PageBlockTable` , if there is a value the field gets populated , if it is null i get an empty field ,  If there is no data , it is blank. Is this a Bug? if not how can i bring an empty text field in the place of blank.
[image]

**VF PAGE BLOCK TABLE :**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!perfservicelist}" var="perfservicelst" id="perfservices">
    <apex:column >
       <apex:facet name="header">Field Check</apex:facet>
       <apex:repeat value="{!perfservicelst.AssService__r}" var="as">
       <apex:inputField value="{!as.PerformDate__c}"/>
       </apex:repeat>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">No Of Occurrence</apex:facet>
        <apex:repeat value="{!Service}" var="c">
        <apex:inputField value="{!c.Occurrence__c}" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:column>    
    <apex:column value="{!perfservicelst.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!perfservicelst.AccountID__c}"/> 
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

**LEFT OUTER JOIN QUERY :**

```
SELECT AccountID__c,Name,(SELECT PerformDate__c FROM AssService__r) FROM  ResService__c
```

Comment: of course if any field doesn't contain any value then it will show blank as value.

Comment: @doga do u have any idea how to bring an empty text field instead of blank one

Comment: try using apex:inputText if that helps. Share some VF code also

Comment: that too not working, giving the same result bro

Comment: can you add your VF page code here? That may help in understanding.

Comment: Maybe you can't access these particular records due to security/sharing rules?

Comment: if so , i shouldn't have got any values from it.

Answer (score 1):

there are no child records for perfservicelst.AssService__r, therefore no input fields are rendered at all

it might be worth evaluating if a Wrapper is a better solution

**UPDATE**

**Controller**

```
public class MyController {

    Wrapper[] wrappers;

    // return list of wrappers containing the account records
    public Wrapper[] getWrappers(){

        if (wrappers == null)
        {

            wrappers = new Wrapper[]}{};
            Account[] record = [SELECT AccountID__c,Name,(SELECT PerformDate__c FROM AssService__r) FROM  ResService__c];

            for (Account record:records)
            {
                wrappers.add(new Wrapper(record));
            }
        }

        return wrappers;
    }

    // wrap account and service records
    public class Wrapper {

        public Account account {get;set;}
        public AssService__c service {get;set;}

        public Wrapper(Account record){
            this.account = record;
            // use existing service or init a new one
            this.service = record.AssService__r.length() > 0 ? record.AssService__r : new AssService__c()
        }

    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper" id="perfservices">
    <apex:column >
       <apex:facet name="header">Field Check</apex:facet>
       <!-- MODIFIED -->
       <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.service.PerformDate__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <!--

    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">No Of Occurrence</apex:facet>
        <apex:repeat value="{!Service}" var="c">
        <apex:inputField value="{!c.Occurrence__c}" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:column>
    -->
    <apex:column value="{!wrapper.account.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!wrapper.record.AccountID__c}"/> 
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: how can it be done could you help me

Comment: @Aravind30790 added a sample